# Todo application for web or Linux machine

Tags: open-source, project-management

There are too many todo list applications, though it's still hard to find a good one which fits my criteria:

1. should not store any data on remote servers I can't control
2. open source (so I would be able to modify it)
3. accessible via web interface (or can be easily synced between devices)
4. lightweight application (I don't think such application should take a lot of resources)
5. supports priority and archives and timestamps for each task
6. would be nice if app is written in Python

I almost found the ideal application (especially in the way it looks and works) - [tyto](https://github.com/jh3y/tyto), though it's too heavy (doesn't fit #4), uses only local storage (so I didn't find the way to sync between devices) and does not support timestamps for tasks (or I'm too bad in manual reading).

So please advise if there is an application which fits my criteria.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OP's example of a near-miss in "[tyto](https://github.com/jh3y/tyto)" immediately suggests [Trello](https://trello.com/), which has your data on their server, and is not opensource. There are some "clones" (I use the word advisedly), though, which might meet the need. The ones I'm aware of (not having actually *used* any) include:

- [Kanboard](http://kanboard.net/);
- [TaskBoard](http://taskboard.matthewross.me/); and
- [Wekan](https://wekan.io/).*

<sub>* Appears to be the new name of what was formerly listed as "LibreBoard".</sub>

So far as I'm aware, they all **satisfy** these requirements:

- should not store any data on remote servers I can't control
- open source (so I would be able to modify it)
- accessible via web interface (or can be easily synced between devices)
- light weight application (I don't think such application should take a lot of resources)

Although I'm not sure about these:

- supports priority and archives and timestamps for each task
- would be nice if app is written in python